# Self Signing certificate for soap web request ANDROID

Tags: android, security, ssl-certificate, android-ksoap2, pinning

How can we self sign the soap request like Get and post request please provide any example or tutorials for the same.
I also referred to the [link](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) but I was not able to graph for soap request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for using/creating selfsigned certificate for Https communication you can use java keytool or openssl for generating certificates.

Look at link: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/GeneratingSelfSignedCertificateWithKeytool?_sscc=t

please add more details to your question to get more information from users.